# How to give SSL encryption to a python chat program?

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, chat

I made a little chat program, and I'm using in to chat with a friend over WAN.

We are now worried about security: our program just uses socket module to send byte encoded strings.

**How would this appear to an interceptor?**

How could I use a SSL connection between us two to make our messaging secured?

Will SSL be enough to make our chat 100% private?
Thank you

Also, here is our chat's code:
Server-side:

```py
import socket

HOST = my ip here
PORT = 1234

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORTA))
    print('Listening')
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    with conn:
        print('Connected to', addr)
        conn.sendall(b'')
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
            risp = input('Message: ').encode('utf-8')
            conn.sendall(risp)
            if not data:
                print('Not receiving')
                break
```

client side:

```py
import socket

HOST = 'my ip'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 1234        # The port used by the server
something = ''
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while something!= 'esc'.encode('utf-8'):
        something= input('Your messagge:').encode('utf-8')
        s.sendall(something)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))


print('Received: ', repr(data))
```

Comment: Use SSL/TLS. That's it.

Comment: Transport security is a deep subject.  The industry standard way to do this would be to use TLS - the crypto behind HTTPS.  Since this is a fun little side project, that (I assume?) you don't intend to use for production, you might find it more interesting to implement symmetric encryption using AES with a pre-agreed key.